# How does SQL Server retrieve a plan out of the plan cache?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Simple question. In SQL Server, if a query can make use of an execution plan already in the plan cache, how does it store/retrieve it?

My guess is it uses some sort of dictionary object where the query is the key, but I'm not clear on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the internal representation but SQL Server caches the compiled 
query plan. You can see the plan cache in [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187404.aspx) which returns a row for each query plan that is cached by SQL Server for faster query execution. You can use this dynamic management view to find cached query plans, cached query text, the amount of memory taken by cached plans, and the reuse count of the cached plans.

SQL Server as well caches the Query result. I mean it caches the Data pages which it reads 
in memory. You can check it using [SET STATISTICS IO ON](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259191%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which will output something like below along with other data.

```
logical reads X, physical reads Y
```

Which will let you know whether pages has been read from disk (`physical reads`) or from in-memory cache (`logical reads`).

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm mainly interested in the structure SQL Server uses to store plans, and how it fetches the plan out of that structure (like is it using the query string as a key to look up the plan out of a dictionary object?). 

However, thanks for explaining physical reads vs logical reads. I knew logical was faster, but wasn't exactly sure why. Cheers! =)

Comment: @AaronMedacco, don't laugh at me but I think only a developer from MS SQL Server team can answer that question as it will not even be documented any where (even not in published white paper). Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it should be.